# How can I run the for loop in parallel for a class function in python?

Tags: python, class, parallel-processing, class-method

I have a class `My_mechanism` which contains the function `velocity_params` which writes the results in a `csv` file. I need to iterate over some range but the iteration is very slow (only one CPU core is utilised at once). Is there any way to speed up the process? The present code takes around 10 minutes to execute, finally, I need to iterate for all `i,j,k,l` in `My_mechanism(i,j,k,l,2)`.

```
from crankshaft import *
import multiprocessing
import time

initial_time = time.time()

for i in range(10,20):
    m = My_mechanism(i,50,20,14,2)
    try:
        m.velocity_params()
    except Exception:
        continue

print("Processing time : ",time.time()-initial_time,"s")
```

Comment: If you plan to run these tasks in parallel, don't write in CSV immediately. Collect all data to write in some container and write all this container in the end

Comment: You can create separate [Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) for each `i`. It's better to manage thread count around your CPU cores number

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a compiled C module such as numpy to do the heavy math computations as numpy will parallelize operations on vectors for you, or you can utilize the multiprocessing library you imported.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

parallelism = 4

p = mp.pool(parallelism)

res = p.map(my_mechanism, [x for x in range(10,20)])
```

Although you will need to handle the multiple input parameters in some other way to use the map function, as by default it will only take one.

Comment: Where do you call the function `m.velocity_params()`

Answer (score 0):

Generally writing to a csv file takes a long time. I would recommend running all your data processing beforehand (this can be parallelised) and writing the output at the end.

If you want a more detailed answer, please be more specific about what csv writer do you use, what is your data etc